# Messed up buttons in Tag Watching & Ignoring settings

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, profile-page, tag-watching

Go to [your user page > Settings > Email Settings > Tag Watching & Ignoring](https://stackoverflow.com/users/tag-notifications/current):

[image: Screenshot]

The buttons work, but:

- When the input box is **hidden**, <kbd>Done</kbd> has no use.
- When the input box is **visible**, <kbd>Add a tag</kbd> has no use.

Shouldn't the extra button be hidden?

Comment: I don't think the bug is related to the missing space, but to the fact that both buttons shouldn't be displayed at the same time.

Comment: Yep, what @PhobosFerro said. Here's the corresponding bug report on MSE: [Tag watching & ignoring is bugged in the profile page settings](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/385385/335251)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the time of writing this, this bug seems to have been fixed.

---

***Edit:** A moderator added [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) without adding an answer. Marking this answer as accepted for now.*